# Getting a php variable inside javascript click()?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I get a php variable inside javascript click()? 
My click() code is

```js
$(".sample_icons").click(function(){
 var $srcimg=$(this).children("img").attr('src');
 image_icon($srcimg);
});
```

I have a variable `$price` in a php file and i want something to happen to this variable say increase price when this `click()` is used. `Click()` is in a js file. So how can I pass this variable to js file so that it can be used under `click()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: Already answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314926/how-can-i-edit-a-php-variable-if-i-click-on-a-button

and here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: You can’t alter PHP variable values with JavaScript. The PHP script has been processed by the time the web page is rendered on your screen. PHP is a _server_ side language, JavaScript a _client_ side language.

Comment: @MartinBean Thats why I asked how to integrate js and php.

Comment: @AbyBasheer You can’t “integrate” them. They’re ran at different times. PHP has finished doing its thing by the time JavaScript comes into the equation. You can’t change PHP variables with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into wherever you need the php variable to be.

```
<?php echo $price ?>
```

Comment: so if I add 

     $(".sample_icons").click(function(){
 var $srcimg=$(this).children("img").attr('src');
 image_icon($srcimg);      
        <?php echo $price ?>                                                          
}); 

whether I will get the value of variable price?

Comment: If you have $price set, then the whole code block above will be replaced with the value of $price.

Answer (score 0):

I make use of a hidden input:

`<input type="hidden" id="this_price" value="<?php echo $price ?>">`

```
$(".sample_icons").click(function(){
    var this_price = $('#this_price').val();
    var $srcimg=$(this).children("img").attr('src');
    image_icon($srcimg);
});
```